# Why does PyCharm not recognize errors in the main.py file?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am woking on a Kivy application usign PyCharm, but the problem is that in the `main.py` file, modules, variables that are undefined are not marked as errors.
[image]

At the beginning I thought it was a general problem, but I have tried on different files which name is not `main.py`, and this is working properly.
This is happening only in the `main.py`

How can I solve this? Is it maybe a bug of PyCharm?

I am using PyCharm Professional 2016.3.

Comment: When you say `main.py`, do you mean _your_ `main.py` file? Have you tried it on lots of different files called `main.py` yet?

Comment: @Gloin, I am having this issue just in the file `main.py`. I have created others, for example, called `a.py`, `whatever.py`, and the highlighting is working properly. I even created an empty project just with the `main.py` and it is not recognizing undefined modules, variables.